# Java method doesn't return the first value of a linked list

Tags: java

I am trying to write a peek method for a header linked list class. However, it doesn't return the first value.

```
public E peek () throws NoSuchElementException {
  ListNode<E> temp = highest;
  ListNode<E> r = temp;

  if (temp.next == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
  else r.next = temp.next.next;

  return r.next.value;
}
```

I understand why it doesn't return the first value. Because in my code `else r.next` will already point to the next node in the list. So for 5,4,3,2,1 it will return 4 on the first call instead of 5. temp is pointing to the highest node which is the header node. How can I get the method to return the first value in the list, 5, first?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Just edited it. The question is: how can I get the peek method to return the first value in the list, 5?

Comment: You can use `header.next.value`

Comment: So use "return highest.next.value"? It successfully returns the first value but not subsequent values, 4,3,2,1.

Comment: @user1766888 Check the answer let me know if you have queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to implement Linked list is that `header` should always be empty node in the list so `it should not hold a value`. This way when you call `next` on header you actually go to first element only.

[header http://easy2teach.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/header-linked-list.jpg](http://easy2teach.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/header-linked-list.jpg)

As depicted in above digram as header next is actually the first element of the Linked List

So you Peek operation is not supposed to throw `NoSuchElementException` instead it should return `null` so simple method can be

```
 public E peek ()
 {
   if(check element does exist using size ==0)
      return null;
   else 
      return highest.next.value;
 }
```

Comment: Yes. I understand that header->5->4->3->2->1 but how would you return the other values if peek is called more than once? for example first peek would return 5. but subsequent calls to peek only return 5. How would you traverse the list using only the peek method?

Comment: Peek operation only returns fist element.